# JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to read server challenge

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, ejb, wildfly-10

When I want to access EJB on remote wildfly server from a different server, i get following error.

```
Error: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to read server challenge [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /../wildfly/standalone-/tmp/auth/X.challenge (No such file or directory)]
   DIGEST-MD5: Server rejected authentication
```

If i access EJB within the server, i don't get any auth error. I use following to access server;

```
http-remoting://server1:8080
```

Basically if i call this in server1, there is no problem. If i call this from server2, i get the error. I assume it looks for auth file in server2 which exists in server1.

I am not sure if I have to make some config on EJB or wildfly to enable access from different server. I did go through every steps which are available online but clearly i am missing something.

Comment: I got the same problem but the problem happens when I create a docker container from my jboss but directly from eclipse when i run locally,  it doesnot happen!! any advice ?

Comment: @qleoz12 are you sure you are mapping Wildfly hosts/ports correctly when you run it locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the error with below changes.

It looks like i was using `ApplicationRealm` for remote authentication as well. I updated below line with my jaas realm.

```
<http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
```

Also, i set `SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS` and `SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT` to `false` on client side.

Comment: what does a jaas realm look like ?

Comment: Could you please suggest where is the config file and what is the file name?

Comment: @DilankaM File is standalone.xml under /wildfly/standalone/configuration/

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is the following.
For a local access, the authentification is not required.
For a remote access, the authentification is required, so I'd suggest to double check the user account and password first.

Comment: user/password is correct. Also, even if it is wrong, it should return auth is failied instead of 'mechanisms' failed.